# Get the size of group activities in aggregated feeds

Tags: getstream-io

When using Aggregated Feed, How can I fetch the size of all activities in a Group of Activity?
As the official documents mentioned "Each activity group inside an aggregated feed contains the 15 most recent activities. If you add more than 15 activities to one group, older activities will no longer be visible. Enterprise customers can contact support to increase this limit.", there is a limit of 15 in getting activities.
Is there any way to fetch length of activities in a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

It returns what it can hold (# of activities in the groups you get). If your limit is increased, it will be higher but it can't include the number of activities that are dropped from the group.

This is a well-known issue and its behavior will be improved to count for all activities, irrespective of their state in group right now.

Comment: Thanks Ferhat. Do you have any estimate for this?

Comment: You mean ETA for the changed behavior?

Comment: Yes. I mean any expecting release date.

Comment: We want to resolve in Q3 but it's an architectural, quite big change. Harder to say more specific at the moment.